# Combine 5 columns into one in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to merge 5 columns into a single one like this:

```
1  4  7  10 13
2  5  8  11 14
3  6  9  12 15
```

to this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

I have this formula and I'm trying to adapt it, but it fails :(

> =IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:B),INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)),IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:C),"",INDEX(C:C,ROW()-COUNTA(A:B)))))

The statement uses 3 IF functions, because it needs to combine 3 columns:

1. For column A, the function compares the row number of a cell with
   the total number of cells in A column that are not empty. If the
   result is true, the function returns the value of the cell from
   column A that is at row(). If the result is false, the function
   moves on to the next IF statement.
2. For column B, the function compares the row number of a cell with the
   total number of cells in A:B range that are not empty. If the result
   is true, the function returns the value of the first cell that is not
   empty in column B. If false, the function moves on to the next IF
   statement.
3. For column C, the function compares the row number of a cell with the
   total number of cells in A:C range that are not empty. If the result
   is true, the function returns a blank cell and doesn't do any more
   calculation. If false, the function returns the value of the first
   cell that is not empty in column C.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: does any of the given answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paste this in a code module

```
Public Function OneDimensionalRange(source As Range)
    Dim index As Integer
    index = Application.Caller.Row
    OneDimensionalRange = source.Cells(index).value
End Function
```

It'll be available for use as a worksheet function.

> =OneDimensionalRange($A$3:$E$3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula, so long as your results are not in the same row or column as the original data (and could be on another worksheet).  In addition, the formula would fail if there are empty cells in the first row or first column.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$3,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA($A:$A))+1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/COUNTA($A:$A))+1),"")
```

The `row` argument and the `column` argument for the `INDEX` function, if you tease it apart, you will see that they return the proper sequence of arguments.  However, you can add any number of columns or rows to the array.

If you want to define the array as being arbitrarily large, so if your **real** array can expand without having to change the formula, then, on another worksheet, (e.g. Sheet2), where `myArtray` is, for example, `Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$100`, try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(myArray,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+1)="","",
INDEX(myArray,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+1,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+1)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your formula and it works as expected, it may be though that you are placing your formula within one of the columns that you reference in your formula which will create a circular reference.

In other words, try using your formula in a column that isn't A, B or C and see what happens.

*Side note:* For what you are trying to achieve I would recommend trying to produce a VBA macro instead, your formula could get quite long and fiddly as you add more and more columns where as a simple macro would let you do something like this with any number of columns.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the requested formula up to S which is where I needed it.

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A),INDEX(A:A,ROW()),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:B),INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:C),INDEX(C:C,ROW()-COUNTA(A:B)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:D),INDEX(D:D,ROW()-COUNTA(A:C)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:E),INDEX(E:E,ROW()-COUNTA(A:D)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:F),INDEX(F:F,ROW()-COUNTA(A:E)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:G),INDEX(G:G,ROW()-COUNTA(A:F)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:H),INDEX(H:H,ROW()-COUNTA(A:G)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:I),INDEX(I:I,ROW()-COUNTA(A:H)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:J),INDEX(J:J,ROW()-COUNTA(A:I)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:K),INDEX(K:K,ROW()-COUNTA(A:J)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:L),INDEX(L:L,ROW()-COUNTA(A:K)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:M),INDEX(M:M,ROW()-COUNTA(A:L)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:N),INDEX(N:N,ROW()-COUNTA(A:M)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:O),INDEX(O:O,ROW()-COUNTA(A:N)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:P),INDEX(P:P,ROW()-COUNTA(A:O)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:Q),INDEX(Q:Q,ROW()-COUNTA(A:P)),IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:R),INDEX(R:R,ROW()-COUNTA(A:Q)),IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:S),"",INDEX(S:S,ROW()-COUNTA(A:R)))))))))))))))))))))
```